# Multiple Taxonomies Using Custom SQL Query

Tags: customization, query

I am running a custom SQL query, and I am trying to pull posts with two taxonomies assigned to it. Here is my query which works:

```
$querystr3 = "SELECT *, 
        events_startdate.meta_value AS the_start,
        events_enddate.meta_value AS the_end
        FROM $wpdb->posts p
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON(p.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)  
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS events_startdate ON(p.ID = events_startdate.post_id AND events_startdate.meta_key = 'events_startdate' )
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS events_enddate ON(p.ID = events_enddate.post_id AND events_enddate.meta_key = 'events_enddate' ) 
        WHERE ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 11
        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'status'
        AND p.post_type = 'pmg_events'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND events_startdate.meta_value != ''
        AND events_enddate.meta_value != ''
        AND events_enddate.meta_value >= CURDATE()
        )
        ORDER BY events_enddate.meta_value ASC";
```

But I'd like to get the posts with TWO taxonomies. So something like this, which obviously doesn't work:

```
$querystr3 = "SELECT *, 
            events_startdate.meta_value AS the_start,
            events_enddate.meta_value AS the_end
            FROM $wpdb->posts p
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON(p.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)  
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS events_startdate ON(p.ID = events_startdate.post_id AND events_startdate.meta_key = 'events_startdate' )
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS events_enddate ON(p.ID = events_enddate.post_id AND events_enddate.meta_key = 'events_enddate' ) 
            WHERE ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 11
            AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'status'
            AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 5
            AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'status'
            AND p.post_type = 'pmg_events'
            AND p.post_status = 'publish'
            AND events_startdate.meta_value != ''
            AND events_enddate.meta_value != ''
            AND events_enddate.meta_value >= CURDATE()
            )
            ORDER BY events_enddate.meta_value ASC";
```

How can I achieve this? Do I need to LEFT JOIN my new taxonomy?

Comment: Did you tried using Wp_Query with taxonomy parameters or it doesn't helps you? here is the ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters, the meta query combined with taxonomy query can help you. can you explain what do you want to fetch?

Comment: I have tried. I'm trying to fetch a custom taxonmy that I have set for the post, as well as the event startdate and enddate, all of which are custom taxonomies. The single taxonomy query works. I'm just trying to query a second taxonomy in that same query. I'd like to pull only the pospts with the status taxonomy set to 5 AND 11. One works, but adding a second does not

Comment: I get the taxonomies part that you want events with status 11 and 5, what about the meta 'events_startdate' and 'events_enddate' are meta values? So basically events whose status is 11 and 5 and startdate != '' and enddate >= CURDATE() ?